# Flash policy-file-request

Tags: node.js, actionscript-3, flash, cross-domain-policy

I am running nodejs based server and I want to use Flash as the interface.

in AS3 I write:

> Security.loadPolicyFile("xmlsocket://151.248.124.213:3843");

so that should load policy file at this adress `http://151.248.124.213:3843/`.
links wouldn't work for now. but here is content of policy file:

```
<cross-domain-policy>
<allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*"/>
<allow-access-from domain="151.248.124.213" to-ports="80"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

And here is the application `http://151.248.124.213/1.html`
But when I start using it, it sends me the message:

```
<policy-file-request/>
```

AS3 talking to server at the same IP:3000.

Nodejs is on VDS server and runs perfectly. When I start SWF from Flash Builder, everything works fine. So the problem must be somewhere in the policy file or in AS3 trying to load one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with this code in policy file server

```
var net = require('net');

var netserver = net.createServer(function(socket){
    socket.addListener("error",function(err){
        socket.end && socket.end() || socket.destroy && socket.destroy();
    });
    var xml = '<?xml version="1.0"?>\n<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM \n"http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">\n<cross-domain-policy>\n';
    xml += '<site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="master-only"/>\n';
    xml += '<allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*"/>\n';
    xml += '</cross-domain-policy>\n';
    if(socket && socket.readyState == 'open'){
      socket.write(xml);
      socket.end(); 
    }
});
netserver.addListener("error",function(err){}); 
netserver.listen(3843, '0.0.0.0');
```

'0.0.0.0' - that is your IP or domain

And that is what you use to connect from flash

```
Security.loadPolicyFile("xmlsocket://151.248.124.213:3843");
```

if you want me to explain some details, let me know.